# Undefined reference to require and exports while using Typescript in gulp and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp

I used to write my web application in plain javascript until I go to know Typescript. Its a good superset of javascript and i didnt have any problem if i write and compile it, and execute it using my WAMP server.

But i heard about angular2( i know angular1 ), i started learning it using https://www.lynda.com/AngularJS-tutorials/Learn-AngularJS-2-Basics/428058-2.html course.

He uses **nodejs**, **gulp**, **gulp-webserver**. I did exact setup as he did, but at the end i got

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined @ animal.ts:1.
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined @ cat.ts:1

Then i switched to first learning how to setup gulp environment from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xOubdqyqaY

here's my project directory structure :

```
typescript/
|--app/
----index.html, load animal.js, cat.js from js/
----|--js, contains all compiles js files( animal.js, cat.js )
-------|--lib, contains all library files
|--node_modules/
|--typescript/, contains my written typescript files 
---|--animal.ts
---|--cat.ts
|--typing/s, contains typescript definition files
|--gulp.config.js
|--gulpfile.js
|--package.json
|--tsconfig.json
|--tslint.json
```

when i run **gulp** command in cmd at root folder(typescript), it runs all the tasks, it compiles all ts files, lint it and serves it using **browser-sync** and **superstatic**. However i got same error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined @ animal.ts:1.
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined @ cat.ts:1

my files content :

**animal.ts**

```
export class Animal {
    constructor( private name: string, private sound: string ) {
    }  
    makeSound() {
        console.log( `${this.name} makes ${this.sound}` );
    }
}
let a: Animal = new Animal( "tiger33", "Gurrrrrr" );
a.makeSound();
```

**cat.ts**

```
import {Animal} from "./animal" 
let b: Animal = new Animal( "Cat", "Mewww" );
b.makeSound();
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong.
I have **node**, **gulp**, **tsc** installed globally.
Do i need to install **browserify** or **requireJS**, but in video they are not using any of this.
Thank you

Comment: Have you added typings for systemjs?

Comment: ...no. But in second one, I don't think its required?

Comment: In angular course, he was using systemjs to load files. But when I used it, it gave me error cannot read split property of undefined. So I directly added script tags to load is files. That's not my problem

Comment: can you add your index.html page? also systemjs configuration if any aprat from what is in index.html

Comment: Can't add more link to original post, First project files : http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01079743288297053535

Comment: Second project : http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07969354539338532950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working using **Browserify**.

Steps [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html).